# how to add zeros after numbers to get a fix length in EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have 3 numbers in excel.
A1. 498
A2. 899
A3. 5209

I want the numbers as the followings:
B1. 49800
B2. 89900
B3. 52090

I am still finding the solutions via online but most of the resource is discussing about leading zeros.

Please, could you kindly give me any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this formula may be of some use:
=A1 & REPT("0"; 5 - LEN(A1))

Thought this does not set the format of the cell itself (which I doubt can be done as you are changing the value of the cell by adding the zeros)

The formula only works if you are dealing with numbers as text, so you may need to convert them to text in the formula (TEXT(A1; "0") instead of A1)

Comment: Thanks @Tom. It is really helpful for me. '=VALUE(A1&REPT("0",5-LEN(A1)))'

Answer (score 0):

you can do this one quite easily without VBA - using an IF and the very handy REPT function:

```
=IF(LEN(H13)<5,H13&REPT(0,5-LEN(H13)),H13)
```

Essentially - if the length is less than 5 - you repeat 0 up to the amount of times that its missing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like simple math to me. Essentially you want to shift left (base 10) a certain number of times. We can do this by:

1. Calculate the ceiling of the base-10 logarithm of the value to get it's "length"
2. Subtract the result from the target "length" of 5, this is the number of places we want to shift
3. Take 10 to this power and multiply back by the value.

In other words, where `x` represents the value in column A you want to transform:

[image: formula]

In Excel, this would be expressed as:

```
=A1*POWER(10,(5-CEILING(LOG10(A1),1)))
```